# Overloading taking precision over Overriding

Tags: java, overriding, overloading

I am facing a problem over this piece of code where I am having Abstract superclass Aninal and Subclass Dog with the method but when i m trying to test valid overload and override here line with  "a.print(d);" is not clear to me . It should invoke dog print method with reference Dog but its invoking one with reference Animal.

```
 public class TestOverload {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Animal a = new Dog();
    a.print(a); // DOG class print method is invoked
    Dog d = new Dog();
    d.print(d);// DOG class print method is invoked
    a.print(d);// PROBLEM ::: it should invoke DOG print method with reference
                         DOG but its invoking 1 with reference Animal


   }
 }

abstract class Animal {
public abstract void print(Animal a);


 }

class Dog extends Animal {
public void print(Dog d) {
    System.out.println(" Dog ");
}

public void print(Animal a) {
    System.out.println("Animal  ");
}
}
```

Can any one clear me over this

Comment: a.print(a); prints Animal not Dog.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you are not right. The output is as follows:

```
Animal
Dog
Animal
```

That is because your method that implements the `print(Animal a)` prints "Animal". So, when you pass in the `Dog` object which is an `instanceof` the `Animal` to the `Animal` object `a` you actually invoke the overriding `print(Animal a)` that prints "Animal". Nothing is fishy here.

Comment: yes , i got the explanation clear to me about reference variable being able to see only the method with Animal reference and even if Dog reference is passed it cast it to Animal and invokes the 1 with Animal reference ..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I run your code, I have the following result :

```
Animal  
 Dog 
Animal
```

So, the `Animal` print method is called each time you are doing `a.print()`, and it's normal, because at compile time, when you call `a.print()`, you are calling the `print()` method of `Animal`, which takes an animal as parameter. The `print(Dog d)` method can't be called here, because it doesn't override the `print(Animal a)` method from `Animal`.

Answer (score 1):

From your example following methods will be executed:

1. `a.print(a)` invokes method `Dog#print(Animal)`
2. `d.print(d)` invokes method `Dog#print(Dog)`
3. `a.print(d)` invokes method `Dog#print(Animal)` since this method implements the abstract method `Animal#print(Animal)`

If you want to execute the method `Dog#print(Dog)` using the object `a`, you need to cast `a` first:

`((Dog) a).print(d) // prints DOG`

Answer (score 1):

Because `a` is of type `Animal` that's why `a.print` is calling print from Animal

Answer (score 0):

Dog is still an instance of animal, thus that behaviour.

If you had the following:

```
public void print(Animal a) {
    if(a instanceof Dog)
        System.out.println(" Dog ");
    else System.out.println("Animal  ");
}
```

It would do what you expect.